# To read value from external configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, maven-3

We are working on Spring Boot Application. Our application runs three server (jvm). Let say these three are : server, worker and myui. These three run in same sequence of server -> worker -> myui. Out of three two run tomcat server.

My issue is that first server if run then Tomcat acquires 8080 port default, its okay for me. But when we run myui, this also start Tomcat, but it throw exception of "**Address Already Bind**" exception because 8080 is already consumed by server.

The build have three types of jar :

***MyApplication***

**config**

- application.properties
- application.yml

**server.jar**

**worker.jar**

**myui.jar**

Each of these jar may have same files as given in config folder. But they will be embedded in the jar and they will not be configuration. In my build user will be allowed to update the application.properties and application.yml.

We have tried with providing "server.port" externally in application.properties as 8090. It works fine in IDE. But it do not work with build as in build the priority of "/config/application.properties" is more than kept inside jar (if any) and it throw address already bind exception.

How can I configure it in "/config/application.properties" so that it can be configurable to change to run myui. How can I access these port value from external properties into my resource java class?

Comment: Do you want to specify the port always?

Answer (score 0):

You could use external **.properties** to do this, remove port configuration from **application.properties** and put it in external files. In Spring Boot application, you can use `@PropertySource` to include these configuration files with environment variable.